# Python minidom: How to access an element

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I'm working on parsing an XML-Sheet in Python. The XML has a structure like this:

```
<layer1>
    <layer2>
        <element>
            <info1></info1>
        </element>
        <element>
            <info1></info1>
        </element>
        <element>
            <info1></info1>
        </element>
    </layer2>
</layer1>
```

Without layer2, I have no problems to acess the data in info1. But with layer2, I'm really in trouble. Their I can adress info1 with: `root.firstChild.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].data`

So my thought was, that I can do it similiar like this:`root.firstChild.firstChild.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].data`

########## Solution

So this is how I solved my problem:
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET

from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET

```
tree = ET.parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for elem in root.findall('./layer2/'):
    for node in elem.findall('element/'):
        x = node.find('info1').text
        if x != "abc":
            elem.remove(node)
```

Comment: Any reason you *have* to use the minidom instead of the ElementTree API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `minidom` API if you can help it. Use the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead; the [`xml.dom.minidom` documentation explicitly states that](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html):

> Users who are not already proficient with the DOM should consider using the `xml.etree.ElementTree` module for their XML processing instead.

Here is a short sample that uses the `ElementTree` API to access your elements:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('inputfile.xml')

for info in tree.findall('.//element/info1'):
    print info.text
```

This uses an XPath expression to list all `info1` elements that are contained inside a `element` element, regardless of their position in the overall XML document.

If all you need is the *first* `info1` element, use `.find()`:

```
print tree.find('.//info1').text
```

With the `DOM` API, `.firstChild` could easily be a `Text` node instead of an `Element` node; you always need to loop over the `.childNotes` sequence to find the first `Element` match:

```
def findFirstElement(node):
    for child in node.childNodes:
        if child.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            return child
```

but for your case, perhaps using [`.getElementsByTagName()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#xml.dom.Element.getElementsByTagName) suffices:

```
root.getElementsByTagName('info1').data
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps me :)

Quick question:

`for context in root.findall('.//element/'):info = context.find('info1').text
if info != a:
root.remove(context)`

Doesnt work. It says, that its not in the list?

Comment: Okay, i figured out a solution by myself :) Thanks for your support guys! I'll edit the question to shwo my result

Comment: @FlorianKanus: No, do not edit your question (because it is your question!) Instead, just accept the best answer (as you have done) or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

does this work? (im not amazing at python just a quick thought)

```
name[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```